# pathspec 'gnulib' did not match any file(s) known to git while building Linux image with Yocto

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, yocto, bitbake

I am building a Linux image using Yocto SDK for QorIQ T1042 PowerPC processor on my Ubuntu 16.04.

My problem is, when I try to build a full image using "bitbake fsl-image-full", there is an error says "pathspec 'gnulib' did not match any file(s) known to git."

I researched many forums but couldn't find any answer. Here is the full log from terminal.

```
|./bootstrap: Bootstrapping from checked-out netcf sources...

| ./bootstrap: consider installing git-merge-changelog from gnulib

| ./bootstrap: getting gnulib files...

| error: pathspec 'gnulib' did not match any file(s) known to git.

| WARNING: /media/hwlab/depo/CalismaBolgesi/YoctoInstallationPoint/yocto/build_mpx1042/tmp/work/ppce5500-fsl-linux/netcf/0.2.8+gitAUTOINC+9158278ad3-r0/temp/run.do_configure.24998:1 exit 1 from

|   ./bootstrap --force

| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /media/hwlab/depo/CalismaBolgesi/YoctoInstallationPoint/yocto/build_mpx1042/tmp/work/ppce5500-fsl-linux/netcf/0.2.8+gitAUTOINC+9158278ad3-r0/temp/log.do_configure.24998)

ERROR: Task 4195 (/media/hwlab/depo/CalismaBolgesi/YoctoInstallationPoint/yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/netcf/netcf_git.bb, do_configure) failed with exit code '1'

NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2036 tasks of which 2031 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed more than 3 years ago in meta-opembedded: https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/commit/?id=093942197237a0b79802d20ebcf3ae0ea35a66bc

Consider updating your layers (or if they come from a vendor, asking them to update the SDK) or backporting the patch.

Comment: Thanks dude you just saved me from going back to ubuntu 14.04 :D